# How to create custom classes that inherit from sqlalchemy models in external library

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

Rather than creating mixin classes that models inherit from, I have a use case that requires me to configure classes the other way around. The classes that would normally be mixin classes need to be the classes that inherit from the models as well as the class that model objects are created from. This is because the models and the mapper configurations are in an external library from the main repository. I need to pass in the host for the engine from the main repository to the models library before any of the models are loaded so they can load with the declarative base already configured. After the engine information is passed in, the session, Base class, and everything is created within a sort of base class that the models inherit from. Here is a simplified example:

```
class SQLAlchemyBase(object):

    metadata = None
    Session = None
    Base = object
    sessionfactory = sessionmaker()

    def initialize(self, host):
        engine = create_engine(host)
        self.metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
        self.Session = scoped_session(self.sessionfactory)
        self.Base = declarative_base(metadata=self.metadata)

models = SQLAlchemyBase()
```

(The models inherit from models.Base)

So the SQLAlchemyBase will be imported into the main repository, the initialize method will be called, passing in the host for the engine, and the models can then be imported. The main repository has its own classes with the same names as the models and have additional methods that a normal mixin class would have to extend functionality. However, I am unable to create model objects using the classes in the main repository because I can't get the mappers to play nice with this unusual inheritance that extends from the external models library. Additionally, in the models library, there are models that have multiple levels of inherited polymorphic relationships. Here is an example that is similar one of the more basic inherited polymorphic relationships:

**Models Library**

```
class Foo(models.Base):

    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    foo_bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo_bar.id"))
    foo_bar = relationship(Foo, backref=backref("foos"))

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type}


class Bar(Foo):

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "bar"}


class FooBar(models.Base):

    __tablename__ = "foo_bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**Main Repository**

```
from separate_library.models import models, Foo as BaseFoo, Bar as BaseBar, FooBar as BaseFooBar


class Foo(BaseFoo):

    @classmethod
    def custom_create_method(cls, **kw):
        foo_obj = cls(**kw)
        models.session.add(foo_obj)
        models.session.flush()


class Bar(BaseBar):
    pass


class FooBar(BaseFooBar):
    pass
```

The original error I was getting was something like this:

> `InvalidRequestError`: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.
>   Original exception was: Multiple classes found for path `Foo` in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.

So I tried putting the full path in the relationships. Then it started giving me an error like this:

> `FlushError`: Attempting to flush an item of type  as a member of collection `FooBar.foos`. Expected an object of type  or a polymorphic subclass of this type. If  is a subclass of , configure mapper `Mapper|Foo|foo` to load this subtype polymorphically, or set `enable_typechecks=False` to allow any subtype to be accepted for flush.

Essentially, the main problem is getting the classes in the main module to point to and act like the model classes. For example, when I try to create relationships, it says it expected an object of type `separate_library.models.Foo` instead of `main_module.models.Foo`. Additionally, in the polymorphic relationships, I can't get the polymorphic_identity to populate for the polymorphic_on column. For example, Bar in the main repository will have the `type` column empty when the object is initially created.

One idea I tried was to add a metaclass to the declarative base in the models library and modify the mappers in the `__init__` method during their initialization. I made progress this way, but haven't gotten it to work completely.

Sorry for the complex explanation, but this is a complex problem. I am not able to change anything about the models or the use case, unfortunately. I have to work within these constraints. If anyone can offer ideas on how to configure the mappers for the classes in the main repository to act like the models in the model library, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems here:

1. When you write `foo_bar = relationship(FooBar, backref=backref("foos"))` the `FooBar` needs to refer to the subclass `FooBar`, not the `BaseFooBar`.
2. `Bar` needs to inherit from `Foo` for the inheritance mechanism to work; it cannot inherit from `BaseFoo`.
3. Your base classes should not have mappers attached to them; otherwise the inheritance mechanism gets out of whack.

The solutions to these problems, in order:

1. Use a string to refer to the class name. This confines the consumer to name their classes a certain way. Let's accept this restriction for now.
2. We can use a metaclass to dynamically change the base class. The metaclass needs to derive from the metaclass of `Base` because SQLAlchemy's declarative extension makes liberal use of metaclasses. We'll see that the metaclass approach can also solve problem 1 in a flexible way.
3. Use `__abstract__ = True`.

Simplest possible example:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr, DeclarativeMeta

class BaseMeta(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if not attrs.get("__abstract__"):
            if len(bases) != 1:
                # you'll need to have multiple inheritance if you have that
                # as well
                raise NotImplementedError()
            base, = bases
            extra_bases = tuple(b._impl for b in base.__bases__
                                if hasattr(b, "_impl"))
            bases += extra_bases
            self = super(BaseMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
            if getattr(base, "__abstract__", False):
                base._impl = self
            return self
        else:
            return super(BaseMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

Base = declarative_base(metaclass=BaseMeta)

class BaseFoo(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)

    @declared_attr
    def foo_bar_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo_bar.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def foo_bar(cls):
        return relationship(lambda: BaseFooBar._impl, backref=backref("foos"))

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type}

class BaseBar(BaseFoo):
    __abstract__ = True

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "bar"}

class BaseFooBar(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    __tablename__ = "foo_bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Foo(BaseFoo):
    @classmethod
    def custom_create_method(cls, **kw):
        foo_obj = cls(**kw)
        models.session.add(foo_obj)
        models.session.flush()

class Bar(BaseBar):
    pass

class FooBar(BaseFooBar):
    pass

print(Bar.__bases__)  # (<class '__main__.BaseBar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>)
```

The basic idea of the metaclass is to inject the class `Foo` into the bases of `Bar`, based on the fact that `BaseBar` inherits from `BaseFoo`, and the fact that `Foo` implements `BaseFoo` (by inheriting from it).

You can add more complicated stuff on top, such as multiple inheritance support or graceful error handling (e.g. warning the user that he's missing a subclass for each base class that you have or he's provided multiple subclasses for the same base class).