# Subclassing Class Inheritance Hierarchies from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I struggled writing this question. It gets into what may be a complicated and uncommon use case.

I have defined several ORM classes in one project which is responsible for maintaining a common database schema and core functionality. For example, let's say this is the `model.email` module.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Integer, Text
from . import Base


class CampaignDB(Base):
    """
    Note: this basic database mapper class is expected to be extended.
    When sub-classing, be mindful to override mappings to other extended classes.
    """   
    __tablename__ = 'campaigns'

    audience_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("audiences.id"))
    active = Column(Boolean)
    name = Column(Text)
```

These ORM classes are imported into several other projects as a package. In some cases, these ORM classes are subclassed to provide additional functionality. For example, here the `CampaignDB` class is subclassed to provide support for sending email in a specific project context.

```
from model.email import CampaignDB

class Campaign(CampaignDB):
    """
    Provides sending capability to the email campaign ORM class.
    """

    def __init__(self, audience_id=None, active=None, name=None):
        self.audience_id = audience_id
        self.active = active
        self.name = name

    def send(self):
        print("send emails to the audience")
```

Now I would like to refactor the `CampaignDB` and subclassed `Campaign` classes to be polymorphic bases using SQLAlchemy's Class Inheritance Hierarchies. For example, I'd like make `CampaignDB` a base class for `EmailCampaignDB` and `PushCampaignDB`. I would then like to extend `EmailCampaignDB` and `PushCampaignDB` separately, as say, `EmailCampaign` and `PushCampaign` in the importing project. However, I would like to still be able to query for `Campaign` and be returned instances of `EmailCampaign` and `PushCampaign`.

I have made several attempts to solve this but run into problems. In particular, `session.query(Campaign).all()` returns no results because SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to consider it as a base class. The generated SQL has the following WHERE clause: `WHERE email.campaigns.type IN (NULL)`

Here's the gist of what I am attempting.

```
class CampaignDB(Base):
    """
    Note: this basic database mapper class is expected to be extended.
    When sub-classing, be mindful to override mappings to other extended classes.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'campaigns'

    audience_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("audiences.id"))
    active = Column(Boolean)
    name = Column(Text)
    type = Column(String(16))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class EmailCampaignDB(CampaignBaseDB):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'email'
    }


class PushCampaignDB(CampaignBaseDB):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'push'
    }

    def send(self):
        print("send push notifications to the audience")

class Campaign(CampaignDB):

    pass

class EmailCampaign(EmailCampaignDB):

    def send(self):
        print("send emails to the audience")

class PushCampaign(PushCampaignDB):

    def send(self):
        print("send push notifications to the audience")
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way to achieve this in this "packaged ORM" context?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621423) is pretty much your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way to make this work by changing the way I think about the problem. I gave up on trying to create and query a `Campaign` subclass of `CampaignDB`. I also used the Declarative API which seems to facilitate subclassing `EmailCampaignDB` and `PushCampaignDB`.

The `model.email` module in the core project:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Integer, Text
from . import Base

class CampaignBaseDB(Base):
    """
    Note: this basic database mapper class is expected to be extended.
    When sub-classing, be mindful to override mappings to other extended classes.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'campaign_bases'
    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {
            'polymorphic_on': cls.type,
        }

    audience_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("audiences.id"))
    active = Column(Boolean)
    name = Column(Text)
    type = Column(String(16))


class EmailCampaignDB(CampaignBaseDB):

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {
            'polymorphic_identity': 'email'
        }


class PushCampaignDB(CampaignBaseDB):

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {
            'polymorphic_identity': 'push'
        }
```

Subclassing the campaign classes in the importing project:

```
from model.email import EmailCampaignDB, PushCampaignDB

class EmailCampaign(EmailCampaignDB):

    def send(self):
        print("send emails to the audience")


class PushCampaign(PushCampaignDB):

    def send(self):
        print("send push notifications to the audience")
```

Polymorphic query:

```
for campaign in db.query(CampaignBaseDB).all():
    campaign.send()

#> send emails to the audience
#> send push notifications to the audience
```

This approach does result in "*SAWarning: Reassigning polymorphic association for identity*", so I still feel like there would be a better way.